# Prove that if A is symmetric positive, $\widetilde{A}=DAD^T$ is also symmetric positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a matrix C, symmetric positive definite, and are given a relationship:

$\widetilde{C}=DAD^T$, how would you show $\widetilde{A}=DCD^T$ is also symmetric positive definite? D is any nonsingular matrix.

The way I approached this was:

$x^tCx=x^tD^-1DCD^tC^-Tx=y^TDCD^t$ where $y>0$

However, this doesnt prove symmetry.
For symmetry, is it just a matter of moving the $^T$ term?

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry is very straight-forward

$$\tilde{A}^T=\left(DCD^{T}\right)=DC^{T}D^{T}=DCD^{T}=\tilde{A}$$

as you said.

Comment: Does the proof look right for positive definite?

Comment: You should edit your question so your proof will be more readable. Currently the equation you wrote is messy.